# scala string formatting with interpolator S not working

Tags: string, scala, string-formatting

I am new to `scala` and trying to do some string formatting.

```
val mAPRegisterResponseMessage = s"{\" 'type' \": \"ap_register_response\",  
 \"message_id\": 02,\"register_status\": $registerStatus,\"host_name_type\": 
 $host_name_type, \"host_name\": $host_name, \"port_num\":$port_num }"
```

If I remove the s in the beginning then the string literal is formed but obviously not correctly. However after adding s at the start, I get an error as ***unclosed character literal*** for the second backslash.
What am I doing wrong? Any clues will help.

Comment: Some background https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476 . It looks like it won't be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use triple quote:

```
s""" {"foo" : 2, "bar": $registerStatus} """
```

Scala console:

```
scala> val registerStatus = "new"
registerStatus: String = new

scala> s""" {"foo" : 2, "bar": $registerStatus} """
res0: String = " {"foo" : 2, "bar": new} "
```

Comment: will this replace $registerStatus with it's value? I was thinking that by using triple quotes, all the string replacements will be lost. let me try and check.

Comment: Strings replacement should work fine. Just don't use backslash character

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1:  triple quotes (`"""`)

as already stated by @mgosk

```
s""" {"foo" : 2, "bar": $registerStatus} """
```

## Solution 2: JSON Library

It looks like you want to create JSON output. For that usecase using string interpolation is not the preferred solution. There are many libraries like for example JSON4s http://json4s.org/ that allow you to use a typesafe case class and render this then as a JSON string

Comment: yes. That's the next step I am going to try. But this was a really hack code which I thought will work quickly but it was taking way more time that needed for this simple formatting(:-

Comment: I would say bad luck :( Never ran in this issue the past six years doing scala. JSON4s as said is a solid starting point.

Answer (score 0):

String Interpolation in Scala is does not work well with escape using `\`. You can use `"""` in the case of special characters.

```
val mAPRegisterResponseMessage = s"""{" 'type' ": "ap_register_response", "register_status": $registerStatus }"""
```