# Scala string formatting: escape sequences

Tags: scala, string-formatting

How do I fix the following string formatting problem involving escape sequences?

```
[~] 17:34:04$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val fullFootnoteId = "asdf"
fullFootnoteId: String = asdf

scala> val footnoteId = 1
footnoteId: Int = 1

scala>  val footnoteTag = s"<sup id=\"ref_${fullFootnoteId}\"><a href=\"#foot_${fullFootnoteId}\">${footnoteId}</a></sup>"
<console>:12: error: value ref_$ is not a member of String
        val footnoteTag = s"<sup id=\"ref_${fullFootnoteId}\"><a href=\"#foot_${fullFootnoteId}\">${footnoteId}</a></sup>"
                                      ^
<console>:12: error: value \ is not a member of String
        val footnoteTag = s"<sup id=\"ref_${fullFootnoteId}\"><a href=\"#foot_${fullFootnoteId}\">${footnoteId}</a></sup>"
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the tip in [scala string formatting with interpolator S not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972841/scala-string-formatting-with-interpolator-s-not-working) , replacing with triple quotes """ fixed the problem.

```
  val footnoteTag = s"""<sup id=\"ref_${fullFootnoteId}\"><a href=\"#foot_${fullFootnoteId}\">${footnoteId}</a></sup>"""
```